# Black-Scholes Model for portfolios

Tags: black-scholes, finance-mathematics

Given Black and Scholes model, consider the portfolio $a_t$  = 1/2, $b_t$ = $1/2$$S_t$ $exp(-rt)$.

1. Show that this portfolio replicates one share of stock.
2. Show if it is self-financing.
3. Find another portfolio which is self financing and replicates one share of stock.

My Attempt:

I'm fairly sure that for Q1, I need to show that this is a arbitrage free portfolio by showing $C_t$ = $V_t$, and not $C_t$ > $V_t$ or $C_t$ < $V_t$ with 
$V_t$ = $a_t$$S_t$+$b_t$$β_t$. However I'm not entirely sure how to find out $C_t$.

For Q2. I believe I need to show that $dV_t$ = $a_tdS_t+b_tdβ_t$ but am not sure how exactly to do that.

I have no idea how to attempt Q3.

Comment: You have a typo in the expression for $b_t$, the xponent is $-r t$. In Q1 you need to show that $S_t = V_t$, which is obvious once you plug in $a_t,b_t, \beta_t$ into $V_t=a_t S_t+b_t \beta_t$

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake. When I plug those values in, I should be getting $V_t = 1/2S_t + 1/2 S_t e^0$ = $S_t$, correct?
For Q2, am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks very much :)
Given the way it's worded, I'm assuming I can just write down another random portfolio which is SF and is arbitrage free for Q3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show whether it is self-financing, we need to show whether the equation
\begin{align*}
dV_t = a_t dS_t+b_t d\beta_t
\end{align*}
holds.
Note that
\begin{align*}
V_t &= a_t S_t + b_t \beta_t\\
&=\frac{1}{2} S_t + \frac{1}{2} S_t e^{-rt} e^{rt}\\
&=S_t.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
dV_t = dS_t.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, 
\begin{align*}
a_t dS_t + b_t d\beta_t &=\frac{1}{2}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}S_t e^{-rt} \big(re^{rt}\big)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}rS_t dt\\
&\neq dS_t.
\end{align*}
Therefore, this is not a self-financing portfolio.

To find another self-financing portfolio that replicates one share of the stock, we can simply set $a_t=1$ and $b_t=0$.